# Box2D Java Shape Access Conditional

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

```
if(tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList().get(0).getType().equals(Type.Chain))
```

OR

```
if(tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList().get(0).getShape().getType(Type.Chain))
```

As I iterate over a list of all the bodies in the world, i want to pick out those that have fixtures of shapeType ChainShape. The code above doesn't work for me. Please tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: It's `||` instead of `OR`.

Comment: that's not part of the code...

Comment: Edit: check your import for Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not test it now, but maybe this helps:

```
if (tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList().get(0).getType()
     .equals(Shape.Type.Chain))
{
   .//
}
```

EDIT: I test now, and works well, check your import for Type.

> com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Shape.Type;

```
if(tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList().get(0).getType().equals(Type.Chain))
```

Comment: THANK YOU. For some reason i had to add Shape.Type instead of just Type.chain.